# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open_workbook'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('stud.data.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print (sheet.nrows)
print(sheet.ncols)
for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
 grades.append([int(sheet.cell(i,1).value), int(sheet.cell(i,2).value), 
 int(sheet.cell(i,3).value)])
 print grades
```

This is the same python code running in other pc but not on my pc. The error is  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open_workbook'. I am running this in Spyder framework. The path or importing the file is correct and have been checked many times.

Comment: Maybe the python version running it is different. Try checking `import sys`
`print(sys.version)` on different machines.